# Installing Laravel auth in an already existing app

Tags: laravel, authentication

I have an existing Laravel app running version 6.2

How would I do the equivalent of `composer require laravel/ui` in an already existing Laravel app.

Comment: composer require laravel/ui is for existing Laravel app, you can run it with existing Laravel app

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run

```
composer require laravel/ui
```

in existing app as well. 
 After that, you can run the following command:

```
php artisan ui vue --auth
```

This command will create the necessary views for authentication and put them in the **resources/views/auth** folder.

Comment: For some reason the first time I was trying it, it was giving me an error.

Comment: Yes, it worked like a charm! Got the app up and running and added authentication to a few pages! You're a real time saver!